# Plotting several probability distributions

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

I want to visualize lognormal probability distributions with different parameters.

I have the following `data.frame` of parameters:

```
 structure(list(country = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", 
"v7", "v8", "v9"), mean = c(47.57, 44.91, 47.15, 44.44, 42.67, 
37.84, 37.91, 44.35, 54.76), sd = c(34.97, 34.4, 34.27, 33.92, 
34.82, 28.19, 30.18, 33.68, 40.48)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Additionally, with the following code, I generate the following plot:

```
# Simulate data from the lognormal distribution
set.seed(123)
num_samples <- 10000  # Choose the desired number of samples
simulated_data <- lapply(1:9,FUN=function(x)data.frame(kost=rlnorm(num_samples, meanlog = 
parameters$meanlog_val[x], sdlog = parameters$sdlog_val[x]),country=country[x]))
table_plot<-bind_rows(simulated_data)

ggplot(table_plot,aes(x=kost,fill=country))+geom_density(alpha=0.3)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

However, it is not so easy to differentiate the different shapes. Maybe do you have any idea how to visualize this difference better?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data? I can't use the `fill` aesthetic since your data doesn't contain country

Comment: If you know the parameters, why are you plotting the kernel density estimates?

Comment: An old trick is to plot tog density, not density. In any case hoping that a reader can distinguish 9 not always very different colours is unduly optimistic. A design that is sometimes effective is to plot each distribution in turn, with the others as backdrop. Elsewhere I have called this a "front-and-back plot".

Comment: It might help to limit the x range to [0, 250]

Comment: Does plotting the mean vs the standard deviation produce the desired visual effect of separating the countries? `library(ggplot2); library(ggrepel);
df <- data.frame(Mean=c(47.57, 44.91, 47.15, 44.44, 42.67, 37.84, 37.91, 44.35, 54.76), SD=c(34.97, 34.4, 34.27, 33.92, 34.82, 28.19, 30.18, 33.68, 40.48), Country=paste("V", c(1:9), sep="")); ggplot(df, aes(Mean, SD)) + geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label = Country))`
`

Comment: really interesting this plot. I have not thought about it. This is the perfect visualization that I am looking.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider just plotting the means vs. the standard deviations.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
df <- data.frame(Mean=c(47.57, 44.91, 47.15, 44.44, 42.67, 37.84, 37.91, 44.35, 54.76),
  SD=c(34.97, 34.4, 34.27, 33.92, 34.82, 28.19, 30.18, 33.68, 40.48), 
  Country=paste("V", c(1:9), sep=""))

ggplot(df, aes(Mean, SD)) + geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label = Country))
```

[image: Plot of mean vs sd]